# Laravel: Table contents changes, how to update existing database foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this table called business impact which has a very simply setup:

id, name, code

And its current content is something like this:

```
1, Major,1
2, Medium,2
3, Minor,3
4, No Impact,4
```

Now I've added another column to it and changed some verbiage around:

```
1, Critical, 1
2, High, 2
3, Medium, 3
4, Low, 4
5, No Impact, 5
```

And we need to update all of the tables in the database so that the new values are reflected in the UI:

Major -> High

Medium -> Medium

Minor -> Low

No Impact -> No Impact

Is there a migration I can run to perform this change throughout the database?

Thank you, just started learning Laravel so don't know any of the ins and outs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a colleague helped out and we were able to make the adjustments using the following migration.

The thing you'll have find are all the tables the target key is used and update it there too:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

        DB::update("UPDATE events SET business_impact_id=5 WHERE business_impact_id=4");
        DB::update("UPDATE events SET business_impact_id=4 WHERE business_impact_id=3");
        DB::update("UPDATE events SET business_impact_id=3 WHERE business_impact_id=2");
        DB::update("UPDATE events SET business_impact_id=2 WHERE business_impact_id=1");

        DB::update("UPDATE event_scopes SET business_impact_id=5 WHERE business_impact_id=4");
        DB::update("UPDATE event_scopes SET business_impact_id=4 WHERE business_impact_id=3");
        DB::update("UPDATE event_scopes SET business_impact_id=3 WHERE business_impact_id=2");
        DB::update("UPDATE event_scopes SET business_impact_id=2 WHERE business_impact_id=1");

        $seeder = new BusinessImpactsTableSeeder();
        $seeder->run();

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```